# fancybox-keep pictures of different sizes in the middle of the iframe

Tags: iframe, fancybox, fancybox-3

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXqYl.png)

i use fancyBox v3.2.11,and you can see this demo in
http://project-08.ithanhua.cn/index.php/home/photo_list/4

$.fancybox.open([
                {
                    src  : 'http://project-08.ithanhua.cn/uploads/article/20180515/153c7b04601118bd4203b2fce31604ca.jpg'
                },
                {
                    src  : 'http://project-08.ithanhua.cn/uploads/article/20180515/153c7b04601118bd4203b2fce31604ca.jpg'

```
            }
        ],{
            type: 'iframe',
            iframe: {
                preload: false,
                // Iframe template
                tpl:
                    '<iframe id="fancybox-frame" name="fancybox-frame" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen allowtransparency="true" src=""></iframe>',
                css: {"width":"1200px"},

                // Iframe tag attributes
                attr: {
                    scrolling: "auto"
                }
            }
        });
```

[resule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLWP8.png)

the image is not in the center
how to do?

Comment: don't use image to post code. Posting code inline makes life easier for anyone trying to help(to copy snippets of your code etc.)

Comment: i post my code .after $.fancybox.open()

Answer (score 0):

Do not use iframes. Why would you want to do that???? This is so wrong, you will lose all features of fancybox - swiping, zooming (basically all gestures), etc. But, if you really have to, then create custom page for displaying image, e.g., display something like `show-image.php?image=myimage.jpg` instead of `myimage.jpg`.

Comment: The point of the scripts like fancybox is that they show resized images and user can zoom-in and drag around, if needed.

Comment: but my client need scrolling effect..if zoom-in the image，some words in the image cannot be read clearly.